# Linq statement only executing once and returning zero on second try and above in foreach loop

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach

Hi I have a piece of code to gather the price of a selection in an observable collection and perform some operations with it via a loop. The code is shown below.

```
      Dim listOfSelectionNames = GameBetCreator.SelectedNumbersString.Split(",")

        For Each selection In listOfSelectionNames
            Dim currentSelection = selection

            Dim price = (From sels In Market.Selections
                               Where sels.Name = currentSelection Select sels.Price).FirstOrDefault()

            Dim returns = (price * omrStake1.UnitStake) + omrStake1.UnitStake

            potentialReturnStringBuilder.AppendLine("Selection " + currentSelection + " Returns " + returns.ToString())

        Next
```

The variable `price` is an int and `market` is a static variable and will never be null. On the first increment within the loop the code works ok and pulls back a value, however every time after that the variable price is set to zero once it hits the linq statement. Before that the `price` variable keeps the value from the previous loop (no idea why).

I have tried to replace the linq with a foreach loop looping through all the selections in `Market.Selections` and do an if statement to check whether the name in that matched the `currentSelection` but it produces the same result. As far as I can see the code should work everytime so im at a loss here. Any guidance will be appreciated

EDIT - SOME EXAMPLES AS REQUESTED

```
listOfSelectionNames = "1", "4", "ODD", "1-12"
```

`Market.Selections`

1. name= "ODD"
   price=2
2. name="1" price=36
3. name="4" price=36
4. name= "1-12" price=12

Note there will never be a scenario where the `listOfSelectionNames` will contain a value that does not have a corresponding `selection.name` in the `Market.Selections` list

Comment: The variable price keep the last value via iterations because you still on the same context, it only be "removed" when you exit the loop. On the other hand, can you show us the content of the array Market.Selections, and the content of listOfSelecionNames?

Comment: Hi the `listOfSelectionNames` is simply just a list of strings that it will cycle through in order to find a price within `Market.Selections`. As for the list of `Market.Selections` it is simply a list of class `Selection` that contains 2 variables `name` which is a string and `price` which is an int. Is there any way of clearing the context at the end of each increment  of the loop? I havent used VB that much so im still trying to get a grasp on it here as well.

Comment: The problem shouldn't be on "cleaning the context", I think the problem is simpler: your "where clause" doesn't match to any item, and "price" is infered as double. Then, if your where clause does not found any item, the FirstOrDefault function, will return 0. Try something: change "Dim price" for "Dim price as double", and "firstordefault " for "first". If it doesn't found any items, it will throw an expection. It will be helpful if you post the real values of the variables.

Comment: The where clause will always match up to an item as no element within the `listOfSelectionNames` can be populated with anything outside of the names contained within the selections of the `Market.Selections` I will try that and add a few examples from within the `listOfSelectionNames` and `Market.Selections` to the question in the meantime

Comment: You are right on the second loop it throws an error `Sequence contains no elements` but the `Market.Selections` is not null and I can see it containing the selection that I want.

Comment: It's very strange, the only clue I can give you is: Market.Selections.Name is DECLARED IMPLICIT as a string? If so, check the spelling (lowercases, spaces etc...) If not, thats the problem, do a cast first, or use "equals". If you let the compiler to infer the type of variable "Name", it should be declaring it as "object", and for compare objetcs you cannot use "=" directly.

Comment: Ive found the issue thanks to your last comment the issue is that the variable name had a setter that trimmed the whitespace `   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) = False Then
                strName = value.Trim` which meant I had to do the same when passing `currentSelection` into the linq statement. No idea why it worked perfectly the first time around however but at least ive got it working now. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the variable name had a setter that trimmed the whitespace `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) = False Then strName = value.Trim` which meant I had to do the same when passing currentSelection into the linq statement.

Therefore the code would look like this

```
 Dim price = (From sels In Market.Selections
                           Where sels.Name = currentSelection.Trim() Select sels.Price).FirstOrDefault()
```

This is posted simply to help others who may have encountered the same problem